# How to split table data separate names Excel files using an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

I'm working with a set of data from SQL Server that I'd like to get into a group of Excel files. This task needs to be automated to run on a monthly basis. The data looks like
sk needs to be automated to run on a monthly basis. The data looks like

```
Site    ID      FirstName   LastName
------  ------- ---------   ---------
North   111     Jim         Smith
North   112     Tim         Johnson
North   113     Sachin      Tedulkar
South   201     Horatio     Alger
South   205     Jimi        Hendrix
South   215     Bugs        Bunny
```

I'd like the results to look like

```
In Excel file named **North.xls**

ID      FirstName   LastName
111     Jim         Smith
112     Tim         Johnson
113     Sachin      Tedulkar

In Excel file named **South.xls**

ID      FirstName   LastName
201     Horatio     Alger
205     Jimi        Hendrix
215     Bugs        Bunny
```

There are between 70 and 100 values in the Site column that I'd like to split upon. I'm using SSIS to perform this task, but I'm getting stuck after I've pulled the data from SQL Server with a OLE DB Source task. What should come next? If there is an easier way to do this using other tools I'm open to that too.

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended question. Generally speaking, on StackOverflow, you should try to make your questions as specific as possible, with examples of what you've tried, and any errors you came across (you already have your expected output listed). But if this were problem, I'd split the problem. Create a source that pulls only the `North` data and creates a `North.xlsx` file. Then create a source that pulls only the `South` data and creates a `South.xlsx` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Execute SQL Task, which executes a SELECT DISTINCT on the column "Site" an stores the values in a object variable.
In the next step you build a Foreach Loop Container, which iterates the object variable.

The Foreach Loop Container has a Dataflow Task. In the Dataflow you have a ADO.NET Source, you build an expression for the SQL-Statement.
In the Expression you build a dynamic SELECT, in the where Part you restrict to the current iteration.
Redirect the Dataflow to a Flat File Destination. In the Expression of the Flat File Destination you can name the File with current iteration.

Do have any questions? Do you need Screenshots?

**Update:**

A more detailed explanation with screenshots:

1. Create a execute SQL Task:

[image]

It should return a full result set and in the SQLStatment property write the SELECT Distinct query on your Site column.

[image]

Define the Result as "0" and map it to a variable of type Object.

2. Create an Foreach Loop Container:

[image]
Set the Enumerator to "Foreach ADO Enumerator" and select your variable, which you have already definided in part 1, in the "ADO object source variable" Combobox.

[image]

Map a new variable of type string in the Resultset. This variable is iteration of the object variable in the Loop.

3. Now you place a Dataflow Task in the ForEachLoop Container.

You can either use an "OLE DB Source" or an "ADO NET Source" as your data source.

4. I will explain the "ADO NET Source":

Add this construct to your Data Flow:

[image]

Configure the ADO.NET Soure like this:

[image]

5. Add an expression to the ADO.NET Source:

[image]

Open the expression editor and select the property [ADO NET Source].[SQLCommand]. In this Expression Editor you can build dynamic SQL querys.

Expression are very powerfull. Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/integration-services-ssis-expressions?view=sql-server-2017

The expression should look something like this:

```
    "SELECT [Site]
      ,[ID]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Sites]
where Site =  '" + @[User::sIterator] + "'"
```

Now every loop passage, the sql-query will select another site.

6. Make the the FileName dynamic with Expressions.

Create an Connection Manger for your "Flat File Destination". 
Select the Expression Property of the connection Manger, like we did before in Part 5 for the Data Flow Task.

[image]

Now build your Expression for the Property "ConnectionString". The ConnectionString is the full Path including the filename.

```
"E:\\" +  @[User::sIterator] + ".csv"
```

Dont forget you have to qoute "\" in expressions with "\". So always write "\\" not "\".

Comment: This is the correct answer but I can see original poster needing help building it.

Comment: Ok thank your for the feedback. I will give him tomorrow a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer.It would be very good if you explained it in more detail with screenshots. Because I'm just starting to learn ssis and I encountered such a problem :(

Comment: @medvedev_ed Here is an example: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/